# iOS contacts request dialog doesn't appear after approved once

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm developing an iOS app that requests access to Contacts. Once the user approves contacts access, it seems that Apple remembers that even if the app is re-installed.
This is a QA nightmare as I need the contacts access confirmation dialog to pop in QA whenever the app requests access to contacts.
Any programatic or manual workaround for this?

Comment: Go to Settings and check privacy settings. And a simulator can be reset completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the QA usually uses test devices they can just `Reset Location & Privacy` so they can see all of the intended permission alerts.

To reset navigate to `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy` (this is a system-wide action, so they'd have to give permission to other apps as well).